# .NET MAUI Layoutproblems between 7" and 10" Tablet

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

To summarize my problem.I m developing a .NET MAUI App which will mostly used on 7" and 10" Tablets.
I use a Bindable Flexlayout to display 5x4 evenly sized tiles with an image inside on the screen.
So far so good for the bigger Tablet, but since i need to display it also correctly on the smaller ones i can`t work with fix Height or width Request, so i m try to get the right Height and Width via the maximum or minimum propertys.
But it wont scale right between these to devices/resolutions.
below is my XAML inside the Bindable Itemtemplate.

Somewhow i can´t make it work.. any ideas?

```
 <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding PageItems}"
                        JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"
                        Wrap="Wrap"
                        Margin="10,0,10,10">

 <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackLayout FlexLayout.Basis="20%"
   Margin="2" >
    <Border Padding="0"
        MaximumHeightRequest="165">
            <StackLayout>
             <StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="{Binding LocalFilePath}"  Aspect="Fill" MaximumHeightRequest="108"/>

                </StackLayout>

                <Label Padding="0"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HeightRequest="50"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   Margin="2"
                   MaxLines="2" />
            </StackLayout>
    </Border>
  </StackLayout>

 </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Edit:
It looks on the 7" Tablet like this:

[image]

10 " Tablet

[image]

Comment: I tested your XAML file and there is no problem, can you provide some code where you use Bindable? I wrote a simple demo, using ‘Grid’ to reach 5x4 pictures can be used normally, you can also try to use ‘Grid’ first.

Comment: I updated the question with the Bindable Itemtemplate and a picture where you can see the problem

Comment: Can you provide a comparison chart using 10 inches? What you can see from your picture is that the `FlexLayout` is not scaling ratio and the label is hidden, right?

Comment: Question is edited. Yeah right.. I need to scale the size of the image depending of the whole width of the flexlayout. but the minimum/maximumHeightrequest seems not fitting

Comment: I would swap those <StackLayout>s for  Grid approach the then work the image scaling.

Comment: that xaml also can't create your examples (no text or background color)

Comment: i removed the unneccessary parts which will not have any effects of the layouting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap StackLayout into Grid like this:

```
    <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
            <StackLayout FlexLayout.Basis="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                     Margin="2" >
                <Border Padding="0"
                    MaximumHeightRequest="165">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="one.png"  Aspect="Fill" MaximumHeightRequest="108"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Label Padding="0"
                           Text="11111"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       HeightRequest="50"
                       FontSize="16"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                       Margin="2"
                       MaxLines="2" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Border>
            </StackLayout>
...
```

7th ipad:

[image]

10th ipad:

[image]